# Excel VBA copy and paste script using Dynamic Range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data sheet that populates other worksheets within the file based upon an advanced filter I created.  I only need to copy certain columns from the advanced filter and not the entire filter depending upon the report desired.  When the advanced filter brings back nothing (meaning there are no matches for that month) the script is copying and pasting the header instead of copying and pasting nothing.  Any suggestions on how to avoid copying and pasting the header when the advanced filter brings back no results?  Here is the script for the first worksheet that gets copied:

```
Sub Populate()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Data")


sht.Range("A1:S400").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:S12"), Unique:=False


Set StartCell = sht.Range("G2")
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

   sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, "M")).Copy
   Worksheets("OC 2016 - Post-65").Range("A18").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


Sheet3.Columns().AutoFit
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: `If LastRow>2 then` and do you stuff.  Don't forget the `End If`

Comment: Thanks Scott, that was the missing link.  I got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may have a similar problem and want to see how I fixed my problem, I'll post what I edited thanks to Scott's answer above.  I'm not an expert, so I may have misplaced the If statement but it is working in what I am doing.

```
Sub Populate()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Data")


sht.Range("A1:S400").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:S12"), Unique:=False


Set StartCell = sht.Range("G2")
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

If LastRow > 2 Then

sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, "M")).Copy
Worksheets("OC 2016 - Post-65").Range("A18").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End If

Sheet3.Columns().AutoFit
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```